# vim sed embedded syntax highlighting

Tags: vim, sed, syntax

I can't get sed embedded syntax highliting work.

I searched and found nothing specifically for sed.

Here's what I've ended up with:

```
if exists("b:current_syntax")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    unlet b:current_syntax                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
endif                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
syntax include @sed syntax/sed.vim                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
syntax region sedEmbed start=+\<sed\>+ end=+'+ contains=@sed
```

But it has no effect.
What's wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

You're close. One problem is that the `start=` and `end=` patterns are by default included in the region. The sed syntax gets confused by those; i.e. it interprets the `sed` already as an `s///` command.

This can be fixed with [`:help :syn-pattern-offset`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-pattern-offset). In a crude way, you let the (syntax include) match only start after the `sed` (end of region start match) + 1 whitespace + the starting single quote (giving `ms=e+1`):

```
syntax region sedEmbed start=+\<sed\>+ms=e+3 end=+'+ contains=@sed
```

But I would rather change the start regular expression and include the starting single quote in the match, handle an arbitrary number of whitespace in between (TODO: also accept sed arguments like `-n` and `-e` if needed). Likewise, the end match needs to be set to before the end region pattern:

```
syntax region sedEmbed start="\<sed\s\+'"ms=e+1 end="'"me=s-1 contains=@sed
```

With that, I am able to highlight something like `sed 's/foo/bar/g'` in a *plain* buffer.

#### Integration with a base syntax

As you've mentioned that you see "no effect" (instead of messed-up highlighting), I suspect you're actually running this syntax extension in a buffer with a preexisting syntax (probably `sh`). That causes additional problems, because the original syntax elements obscure your overlay region, so that it doesn't match.

To fix that, you need to find out which original base syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. (I maintain an [extended fork](https://github.com/inkarkat/SyntaxAttr.vim).)

For me, the following works, but it mutilates the original shell syntax a bit:

```
setfiletype sh
if exists("b:current_syntax")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    unlet b:current_syntax                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
endif                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

" Remove sh.vim syntax items that are "in the way".
syn clear kshStatement
syn clear bashStatement
syn clear shQuote
syn clear shSingleQuote

syntax include @sed syntax/sed.vim                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
syntax region sedEmbed start="\<sed\s\+'"ms=e+1 end="'"me=s-1 contains=@sed
```

#### As a variation of [`:help sh-awk`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#sh-awk)

That documented extension provides an almost perfect blueprint for embedding other languages into the shell script syntax, naming the `syntax/sh.vim` syntax groups that need to be included and extended. To adapt it to `sed`, I made the following changes:

- Still need to clear `bashStatement` and `kshStatement` to avoid that the keyword match obscures the match for the added region.
- Add support for multiple `sed` expressions (`-e ... -e ...`) and line continuation.
- Restore correct `b:current_syntax` value.

```
syn clear kshStatement
syn clear bashStatement

let s:save_syntax = b:current_syntax
unlet b:current_syntax
syn include @shSedScript syntax/sed.vim
let b:current_syntax = s:save_syntax
unlet s:save_syntax

syn match shSedLineContinuation "\\\s*$" contained skipempty nextgroup=shSedExpression
syn match shSedExpression "\%(^\|\_s\+\)-\a*e\a*\_s\+" contained nextgroup=shSedScriptCode
syn region shSedScriptCode matchgroup=shSedCommand start=+[=\\]\@<!'+ skip=+\\'+ end=+'+ contains=@shSedScript contained skipwhite skipempty nextgroup=shSedLineContinuation,shSedExpression
syn region shSedScriptEmbedded matchgroup=shSedCommand start=+\<sed\>+ skip=+\\$+ end=+[=\\]\@<!'+me=e-1 contains=@shIdList,@shExprList2 nextgroup=shSedScriptCode
syn cluster shCommandSubList add=shSedScriptEmbedded

hi def link shSedCommand Type
hi def link shSedExpression shSetOption
```

Comment: we're coming closer, but now this breaks bash syntax hilighting.

Comment: I'm not sure whether what you want actually is achievable. Embedding another syntax requires that the original syntax (here: shell) is prepared for it. Though `syntax/.sh.vim` is written by a true Vim veteran and is quite elaborate, I doubt that this has ever been attempted. So, brace yourself for tweaking the original syntax as well and submitting patches to its author.

Comment: An easier approach would be to put the sed commands on separate lines (e.g. via here-document), and then use plugins like [NrrwRgn plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3075) or (different approach) my own [SyntaxRange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4168) for sed highlighting.

Comment: do you know how syntax/sh.vim is prepared for awk ?
I don't see a reference to awk in it.

i'm gonna keep on trying, and if I get some success/progress, I'll post here.

thank you.

Comment: I don't think there's any integration with awk. There's a separate syntax for awk that gets detected via a `#!/usr/bin/awk` shebang line, but there's no syntax inclusion then. Good luck with your attempts; it would be great if you could find an elegant solution!

Comment: yes, there is. it works great. you can find it at `:h sh-awk`

Comment: Ah, so it's just a recipe, but not active. Anyway, that looks like a great template to follow for sed, too! It has many of the things I've mentioned in my answer, plus some special tweaks to make it work with `sh.vim`.

Comment: 5 hours because I forgot to `unlet s:save_syntax` before sourcing my `syntax/perl.vim` ...  Thank again @IngoKarkat for your snippets